# Gamifying surveys by measuring the ability to discern popular taste

Tags: personality, methodology, survey

I am working on a crowdsourcing platform where participants are given a set of choices between two items (for instance, books or movies). Out of each pair, they are to select an item which they think the majority of participants will choose over the other.

To provide an incentive for the participant, I'd like to turn this into a game. The idea is to reward participants for thinking about their answers, instead of just performing the activity by making arbitrary choices.

The algorithm for the game is as follows:
For every item, the participant is awarded a score based on the % of previous participants who have selected that choice, with the final score being the average of all the individual item scores.

I will only provide scores after a certain number of participants have completed the survey (say, 10).

My question is: Does the algorithm suitably assess the participant's ability to determine the "popular" choice?

The assumption is that participants should score higher if the item they picked is much more favorable than the other, as opposed to when choosing one that's only slightly more favorable (say, 55-45 split). (On the other hand, it probably takes less skill to select "clear winners".)

Comment: Have you considered IRT? I've never heard of using it like this, but IRT can control for the "level" (or popularity) of an item across all participants, including how strict the cutoff is (item discrimination).